# Django: How to stop a value from incrementing when i refresh a page in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two some fields in my Profile model called:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    main_all_earning = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    earning_point = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    referral_point = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    indirect_sign_up = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and i also have the logic in views.py

```
def profile(request):
   ...
user = request.user
    profile = request.user.profile
    my_count = Profile.objects.filter(recommended_by__profile__recommended_by=user).count()
    profile.indirect_sign_up = my_count * signup_point.ind_signup_point
    profile.main_all_earning = profile.main_all_earning + profile.indirect_sign_up
    profile.save()
```

Now whenever i call this profile view, the `main_all_earning` add whatever is in the `indirect_sign_up` and give the new value and so on...
How do i stop this? what i want is for the `main_all_earning` to add whatever that is in the `indirect_sign_up` only once and till there is a new value in the `indirect_sign_up` and not whenever i refresh the page

Comment: IMHO, you should do this count update while updating the Profile model for a user. Whenever there is a change in the `indirect_sign_up` field run the count update code. updating count only on profile visit may lead to incorrect count for users. `pre_save` signal might be useful.

Comment: @KiranParajuli okay i get it, can you please show me some code so i can get started?

Comment: I've posted an answer with signals approach. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you should do this count update while updating the Profile model for a user. Whenever there is a change in the indirect_sign_up field run the count update code. Updating count only on profile visits may lead to incorrect counts for users. For me, the best placement can be at the point where the `indirect_ref_signup` update occurs.

Else, Signals can work best for you. We can work on a `pre_save` signal for this count update:

- check if this is a save signal not create
- check if current `indirect_ref_signup` has changed

```py
# signals.py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_delete,pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Profile)
def update_indirect_signup_count(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.id is None:
        # this is on create event
        pass
    else:
        current=instance
        previous=Profile.objects.get(id=instance.id)
        if previous.indirect_sign_up!= current.indirect_sign_up:
            # update code here
            # save the instance
            instance.save()
```

Comment: @thanks for the answer, i would need to implement this in the views.py or models.py?

Comment: a separate file will be clean. create `project/app/signals.py` and `apps.py` should load signals on ready. see here https://github.com/word-club/backend/blob/main/account/apps.py

Answer (score 1):

You could simply check *if* the `indirect_sign_up` value will change:

```
def profile(request):
   ...
    user = request.user
    profile = user.profile
    my_count = Profile.objects.filter(recommended_by__profile__recommended_by=user).count()

    temp_indirect_sign_up = my_count * signup_point.ind_signup_point
    if profile.indirect_sign_up != temp_indirect_sign_up:
        profile.indirect_sign_up = temp_indirect_sign_up
        profile.main_all_earning = profile.main_all_earning + profile.indirect_sign_up
        profile.save()
```

Comment: thanks for your response, now it doesn't increment on each page refresh but whenever there is a new value in the `indirect_sign_up` instead of the the `main_all_earning` to get the just the new value and update it in the `main_all_earning` is still takes the whole `indirect_ref_signup` and add it to current `main_all_earning`. the bug where it increments on each page refresh is gone, but this happens whenever there is a new value in the `indirect_ref_signup`